# Как сделать компонент невидимым, не изменяя расположение других элементов?

Tags: java, swing

Есть 2 кнопки: "Вперед", "Назад" для прохождения по списку. Когда достигнут конец, кнопка "Вперед" должна исчезнуть, но кнопка "Назад" не должна перескочить на её место. Использую `setVisible(false)`, но кнопка "Назад" перескакивает на место кнопки "Вперед". 
Менеджер расположения GridBagLayout.

Comment: Может, лучше сделать кнопку `setEnabled(false)`, а не невидимой?

Comment: Это первое, что мне пришло в голову) Но пока ищу возможность убрать её вовсе. Если невозможно, то задизэйблю.

Comment: Было бы хорошо ваш код увидеть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имхо, идея сама по себе бредовая, но варианты есть:

1. Написать свой layout manager (а если быть точным, то перегрузить пару методов из уже существующего)
2. Этот кажется проще: вместо 2х кнопок пихаешь панель. Этой панели устанавливаешь [grid layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html). На панель добавляешь кнопки в нужные ячейки сетки.

p.s. Я всегда считал, что исчезающие элементы управления - это пример типичного уг-дизайна. Свое мнение не навязываю, прошу просто подумать над этим. Единственное, где оправданно такое решение, - изменение функций приложения в зависимости от прав доступа (обычным пользователям необязательно знать, какие функции есть у кого-то, кто находится выше в пищевой цепочке).

Answer (score 0):

Единственное решение, которое нашел: использовать другой менеджер расположения. Использовал Jgoodies.